# How to force SQL Server to only allow one insert of record every 3 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I need a way to force my database to allow only one insert of a certain record in a period of 3 minutes.

For example, If I insert a record with the phone number 3053333333, I need a way to force no more entries of the same phone number until 3 minutes later.

I need to do this at the database level. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just limit how the insertions are done?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is an instead of insert trigger.

Comment: Why does it need to be at the database level?Would be easy to do at a database abstraction level.

Comment: I was thinking using an store procedure with a where clause for the insertions, and check the condition in the where clause, but this wouldn't be 100% accurate, because what happens if two insert requests are done with a microsecond difference, maybe when I'm checking the second one the first one have been not finished, so maybe both of then finished inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for, but it should be a good enough approximation.
The good thing about this method is that it is easy to implement and efficient. No triggers required.

Add an `int` column to the table that would be automatically populated with the default value using this expression:

```
datediff(minute,'2001-01-01',getdate())/(3)
```

This expression calculates how many minutes (divided by 3) has passed since some reference date (2001-01-01).

Then add unique index on both `PhoneNumber` and this `PhoneTimestamp` columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PhoneTimestamp] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TestTable_PhoneTimestamp]  
    DEFAULT (datediff(minute,'2001-01-01',getdate())/(3)),
CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PhoneNumber] ON [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [PhoneNumber] ASC,
    [PhoneTimestamp] ASC
)
GO
```

Insert values to the table without setting the `PhoneTimestamp` explicitly, let the default expression work:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] ([PhoneNumber]) VALUES
('124');
```

The first `INSERT` will work fine, but if you try to run it again within the same 3-minute "slot" it will fail with the message:

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TestTable' with unique index 
'IX_PhoneNumber'. The duplicate key value is (124, 2649888).
The statement has been terminated.
```

It is an approximation, because you can insert two rows less than 3 minutes apart. If the first row is inserted, say, at `10:02:58` and the second is inserted at `10:03:02`, it will be accepted. But, if you insert a row at `10:03:02`, then the next row will be accepted only after `10:06:00`.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert if there's not already a record within the last three minutes.

```
DECLARE @ThreeMinutesAgo datetime2 = 
    DATEDIFF(minute, -3, getdate())

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM PhoneRecords 
    WHERE PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber 
    AND TimeStamp > @ThreeMinutesAgo)
  INSERT INTO PhoneRecords 
    (PhoneNumber, TimeStamp, MoreStuff) 
    VALUES 
    (@PhoneNumber, getdate(), @MoreStuff)
```

---

**EDIT** to address Vladimir's comment below:

I'd go about this using a second table with PhoneNumber as a key, to track the most recent record.

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers (
    PhoneNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LastTimeStamp datetime2
)
```

PhoneNumber would be a foreign key in the PhoneRecords table.  To add a new record:

```
DECLARE @Timestamp datetime2 = getdate()
DECLARE @ThreeMinutesAgo datetime2 = 
        DATEDIFF(minute, -3, @Timestamp)

UPDATE PhoneNumbers 
    SET LastTimeStamp = @TimeStamp
    WHERE PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber AND LastTimeStamp < @ThreeMinutesAgo
```

That only worked if the timestamp was over 3 minutes old -- and note that if another process is updating the record, I have to wait for it to be unlocked to try my update.  So if I got to make the update,

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
    INSERT INTO PhoneRecords 
        (PhoneNumber, TimeStamp, MoreStuff) 
        VALUES 
        (@PhoneNumber, @Timestamp, @MoreStuff)
```

You'd want to put that in a transaction, and also check for needing to insert a phone number in the PhoneNumbers table the first time.

Comment: How would you make it work 100% reliably when there are multiple attempts to insert the same value at the same time? I refer to the concern that OP wrote in the comments to the question.

Comment: Added an edit above to address this @VladimirBaranov

Comment: @VladimirBaranov:  I like your approach to this, the result is very concise: TRY -- do insert -- CATCH -- do nothing.  

My issue with that is that I try not to use a `CATCH` for expected conditions.  Is there any performance consideration for that?  What if this is a condition that happens not rarely, but maybe there are MOSTLY fails? I wonder if there is any performance penalty for trying to insert a bad foreign key, compared to checking for a valid one first.  It may depend on how frequently you're trying to add unwanted records compared to valid ones.

Comment: My answer was focused on declaring the needed constraint using built-in DB mechanisms, not on performance. Your approach is also valid. I recently came across the [Performance impact of different error handling techniques](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling) post by Aaron Bertrand, check it out. Still, you should do your own tests for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

store a time stamp on the record upon insert.

At every insert, check that current time vs the last time stamp of the same phone no is at least 3 minutes.

If you are doing the insertion via Stored Procedure, implement the checking there. Else you will have to do it in a trigger